# Can I get Eclipse to autocomplete load-> instead of just load?

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

I am using CodeIgniter and Eclipse PDT; is it possible to get eclipse to autocomplete *loa* as `load->` instead of `load`? Similair to how you get `$this->` automatically.

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, lemiant! I don't know if there's a pre-built plugin, but I think PDT can be set up to read class information and the like. Check out this discussion on the CodeIgniter forums to see how people have apparently been implementing this over the last few years:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/69098/

It appears there are some hacky ways to do it, but it doesn't seem impossible by any means. Hope this helps.